# Google App Engine Python - send_mail and separate HTML form

Tags: python, html, forms, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up a contact form in GAE from a separate jinja template. Get method work as expected and render the HTML template correctly. However I'm stuck with the post method using send_mail function to send emails from the contact form. I believe is something related to the form action parameter/query parameter but i miss something, i'm honest.
Her's part of the code.
thanks in advance.

```
class SendEmail(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    email = self.request.get('email')
    subject = self.request.get('subject')
    message = self.request.get('message')
    template_values = {
                       "name": name,
                       "email": email,
                       "subject": subject,
                       "message": message,
                       }

    template = jinja_env.get_template("/contact.html")
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

def post(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    email = self.request.get('email')
    subject = self.request.get('subject')
    message = self.request.get('message')
    invia_mail = mail.send_mail(sender="email", to="myemail@gmail.com", 
                                subject="subject", body="message")



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/contact.html", SendEmail)], debug=True)
```

and the html form:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
<form role="form" method="post" action="/?">  
<div class="form-group">
  <h2>Contattaci</h2>
  <label>Nome:<input size=50 name="name" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo Nome"></label><br>
  <label>Email:<input size=50 name="email" placeholder="Inserisci un indirizzo email valido"></label><br>
  <label>Oggetto:<input size=50 name="subject" placeholder="Cosa vuoi chiederci?"></label><br>
  <label>Messaggio:<input size=50 name="message" placeholder="Scrivi il tuo messaggio!"></label>
  <br /> <input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia" class="button">
 </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The sender will have to be a administrator in your project for it to work when deployed. The email will not send locally (unless you've set it up) but it will appear in the dev_appserver logs.

Comment: Temporarily comment out the `mail.send_mail` statement and use a logging statement with the relevant info. This will tell you if the problem is on the HTML form side or on the actual email sending side.

Comment: thank you both guys, you put me in the right direction. Relying on send_mail_to_admins and logging statement i figured out what the problem was. i don't need the action parameter and now i'm able to pass in my variables and concatenate them. i just miss some data validation rule now. thank you!